# max and min sine function and all intervals

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I have a calculus question:

The voltage signal from a standard North
American wall socket can be described by the
equation **V(t) = 170sin(120πt)**, where t is time,
in seconds, and V(t) is the voltage, in volts, at
time t.

a) Find the maximum and minimum voltage
levels, and the times at which they occur.

Basically I understand that my maximum is 170 Volts, my minimum is -170 Volts but it is asking for the exact times at which they occur. So my answer turns out to be :

t = {t | t = (4k+1)/240, k >= 0, k ∈ Z}  <- Max

t = {t | t = (4k+1)/240, k >= 0, k ∈ Z}  <- Min

I am VERY confused as to how those above intervals came to be and if for example the question was a cosine function instead of sine, would it be different?

Thank you very much everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct to recognize that the amplitude is 170 so the maximum will be 170 and the minimum will be -170.

$\sin(t)$ has a period of $2\pi$ and a maximum at every $\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi *k$ and a minimum at every $\frac{3\pi}{2}+2\pi*k$ where $k$ is a constant.

The major difference between the functions is the period. In your function, $V(t)=170\sin(120\pi t)$, the coefficient of $t$ is $120\pi$, which means that the function travels $120\pi$ times as fast, or completes a period $120\pi$ times faster than usual. Since $\sin(t)$ has a period of $2\pi$, then $V(t)$ will make one period in $\frac{2\pi}{120\pi}$ or every $\frac{1}{60}$.

Recall that $\sin(t)$ has a maximum every $\frac{1}{4}$ of the way along a period. This means that the first maximum will be reached at $\frac{1}{4}*\frac{1}{60}=\frac{1}{240}$. Since the function has a period of $\frac{1}{60}$, then you can continuously add $\frac{1}{60}$ to $\frac{1}{240}$ to obtain more maxima, which would then mean maximums are when:

$$t=\frac{4k+1}{240}$$

where $k$ is an integer greater than or equal to $0$.

Since a minimum occurs every $\frac{3}{4}$ of a period, using similar logic we find that the minima are at:

$$t=\frac{4k+3}{240}$$

again where $k$ is an integer greater than or equal to $0$.

Comment: Just look a took into this and I FINALLY get it. Thank you so much! So if for example it was a cosine function I would look for where the cos function is maximum and minimum?

Comment: Also quick question, the answer should be 2k+1/240. Right? For the maximums?

Comment: Yes. It would be extremely similar, since cosine is simply sine shifted to the left pi/2 units.

Comment: It should be 4k, not 2k. I'm not sure where you got the 2k from since k/60 + 1/240 = (4k+1)/240

Comment: The answer shows 2k+1. Possibly an error? Thank you though!

Comment: For example if the equation was changed from sin to cos, then should my maximum be something like: (2(pi)n + 2(pi))/120pi  ? and my minimum at: (n(pi) + 2(pi))/120pi correct? Or something along the lines of that?

Comment: Since cos has a maximum at the beginning of every period the maxima would be at 4k/240 and since it has a minimum at every halfway through a period the minima would be at (4k+2)/240

Comment: @Winple Thank you very much! Very helpful! I think i finally get this and will continue to do more questions as practice